# Emacs not filling out terminal framebuffer

Tags: terminal, emacs

Ive recently started using emacs and i have the weird issue that my emacs session is not filling out the whole terminal

[image]

the black frames right and at the bottom should be white

how do i solve this

im using the emacs github theme

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your terminal is resizing based on pixels while emacs is sized based on the height and width of the characters within the terminal.  For GUI emacs frames you can set `frame-resize-pixelwise` to `t` to make emacs take up the available space but I don't think that's going to work for terminal based emacs.